# How can I run javadocs from gradle in the local project only?

Tags: gradle

I am a `gradle` newbie, using it in an extraordinarily enterprisey multiproject build.

It appears that the standard java plugin has been applied.

When I run `gradle javadoc` in my local project, it seems that `gradle` tries to run `javadoc` in many of the projects listed in its dependencies stanza in its `build.gradle` file.

Because many of these projects have bad `javadoc` tags, the doclint "feature" of `javadoc` causes them to fail.

I've figured out how to pass through the "none" option to the doclint feature, but that didn't seem to "stick" through the dependent projects.

I don't care about these projects.  I just want to run `javadoc` on my project's source files.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried this:

`gradle :path:to:myproject:javadoc` ?

Maybe it will not help, if your project depends on other projects.
You can exclude some task from execution:

`gradle javadoc -x :path:to:otherproject:javadoc`

Or you can disable javadoc on other projects.

Just add `javadoc.enabled = false` to the projects that doesn't need javadoc.

**UPDATE**

You can add something like this to all your projects to skip the execution of javadoc:

```
javadoc{
  onlyIf {project.hasProperty('javadoc') &&
          project.getProperty('javadoc') == project.name}
}
```

and then you can run your task with this property:

```
gradle javadoc -Pjavadoc=myproject
```

Comment: Due to the enterprisey nature of the gradle build I'm forced to work with, there are _dozens_ of projects this one tiny subproject depends on.  I see no way to run javadoc on just _it_.  I probably could use `-x` several dozen times but to me that's not a solution.

Comment: See my update above. We had a similar issue and resolved it like described above.

Comment: Thanks. I can't change the upstream projects.  :-(

Comment: You can do it in parent project. Just loop over all projects and look for javadoc. Set project.tasks.javadoc.onlyIf = ....